# How can I get plain text from within a HTML class given a URL in python?

Tags: python, html

How can I get plain text (stripped of HTML) from inside a any tag with the class name of calendardescription given a URL in python? Matching text in different tags should also be separated by a blank line. This is for text to speech purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the popular library: [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

[Here is the documentation.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

Answer (score 1):

look in the direction of beautiful soup.